# Echo back the images sent to the echobot2.py telegram bot

Tags: python, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot

I tried the [echobot2.py](https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot/blob/master/examples/README.md#echobot2py) of the [python-telegram-bot](https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot) library but it does not echo the images sent to the bot. How can I handle this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not supposed to echo images in that example.

You can see from line 65 it is using `Filters.text` which means it only captures text messages. If you want to echo images, you should add another `MessageHandler` with `Filters.photo` and add a function to do `update.message.reply_photo(update.message.photo[-1])`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. What is that [-1] over there?

Comment: `message.photo` is a list of `PhotoSize` objects ordered by ascending size, which when you send a photo on telegram, they renders the photo into different sizes (for different uses like thumbnails). `[-1]` means taking the last element of the list, which is the largest one